# AttributeError: Gentoo instance has no attribute 'installers'

Tags: ros, rosdep, ros-electric, rosinstall, gentoo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Trying to update my install failed, so I tried a fresh one.

```
$ rosinstall ~/ros "http://packages.ros.org/cgi-bin/gen_rosinstall.py?rosdistro=electric&variant=desktop-full&overlay=no"

... stuff stuff stuff ...

Bootstrapping ROS build
Detected ros_comm bootstrapping it too.
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['ros',     'ros_comm']                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory/home/murph/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-    20110908-112513                                                                                                                                                                                        
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['ros', 'ros_comm'] to:
['rosdep', 'rosemacs', 'rosclean', 'roscreate', 'rosunit', 'rospack', 'rosmake', 'rosbash', 'rosboost_cfg', 'test_roslib', 'test_rosdep', 'test_roscreate', 'test_rospack', 'test_rosmake', 'roslib', 'rosbuild', 'roslang', 'mk', 'roslisp', 'rospy', 'roscpp', 'roscpp_traits', 'roscpp_serialization', 'xmlrpcpp', 'roswtf', 'cpp_common', 'rostime', 'message_filters', 'roscore_migration_rules', 'rosconsole', 'rosmaster', 'rosout', 'rosmsg', 'rosbag', 'roslaunch', 'rostopic', 'rosparam', 'rosgraph', 'rosbagmigration', 'rostest', 'rosnode', 'rosservice', 'topic_tools', 'std_srvs', 'std_msgs', 'rosgraph_msgs', 'test_topic_tools', 'test_roscpp_serialization_perf', 'test_roslib_comm', 'test_crosspackage', 'perf_roscpp', 'test_roscpp_serialization', 'test_roswtf', 'test_rosmsg', 'test_roscpp', 'test_rosbag', 'test_rostopic', 'test_rosparam', 'test_rosgraph', 'test_rosmaster', 'test_roslaunch', 'test_ros', 'test_rosservice', 'test_rostime', 'test_rostest', 'test_rosnode', 'test_rospy']
[ rosmake ] Generating Install Script using rosdep then executing. This may take a minute, you will be prompted for permissions. . .                                                                                                                                           
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/murph/ros/ros/bin/rosmake", line 65, in <module>
if rma.main():
  File "/home/murph/ros/ros/tools/rosmake/src/rosmake/engine.py", line 855, in main
self.rosdep_install_result = self.install_rosdeps(buildable_packages, options.rosdep_yes)
  File "/home/murph/ros/ros/tools/rosmake/src/rosmake/engine.py", line 311, in install_rosdeps
r = rosdep.core.Rosdep(packages, robust=True)
  File "/home/murph/ros/ros/tools/rosdep/src/rosdep/core.py", line 343, in __init__
self.yc = YamlCache(self.osi.get_name(), self.osi.get_version(), self.osi.get_os().installers)
AttributeError: Gentoo instance has no attribute 'installers'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/murph/ros/ros/bin/rosmake", line 65, in <module>
if rma.main():
  File "/home/murph/ros/ros/tools/rosmake/src/rosmake/engine.py", line 855, in main
self.rosdep_install_result = self.install_rosdeps(buildable_packages, options.rosdep_yes)
  File "/home/murph/ros/ros/tools/rosmake/src/rosmake/engine.py", line 311, in install_rosdeps
r = rosdep.core.Rosdep(packages, robust=True)
  File "/home/murph/ros/ros/tools/rosdep/src/rosdep/core.py", line 343, in __init__
self.yc = YamlCache(self.osi.get_name(), self.osi.get_version(), self.osi.get_os().installers)
AttributeError: Gentoo instance has no attribute 'installers'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/rosinstall", line 5, in <module>
pkg_resources.run_script('rosinstall==0.5.20', 'rosinstall')
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 500, in run_script
self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1236, in run_script
execfile(script_filename, namespace, namespace)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/rosinstall-0.5.20-py2.6.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/rosinstall", line 599, in <module>
sys.exit(not rosinstall_main(sys.argv))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/rosinstall-0.5.20-py2.6.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/rosinstall", line 590, in rosinstall_main
subprocess.check_call("source %s && rosmake ros%s --rosdep-install%s" % (os.path.join(options.path, 'setup.sh'), ros_comm_insert, rosdep_yes_insert), shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 488, in check_call
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'source /home/murph/ros/setup.sh && rosmake ros ros_comm --rosdep-install' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11152/attributeerror:-gentoo-instance-has-no-attribute-%27installers%27/) by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1033 on 2011-09-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found a patch on the tracker, seemed to fix everything when applied!

https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3664

Thanks!

---

Originally posted by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) with karma: 1033 on 2011-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) on 2012-01-11**:
Just commenting: I wrote some code that fixes up rosdep on Electric to love Gentoo quite a bit. https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3742 <-- if anyone else wants it.